# hasClass doesn't function as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, onclick

I have a list of li items and would like to trigger a button click if **2 classes are found**.

When a list item has 2 classes, I would like to trigger the btn with a click. Can you guys take a look for me?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var $html = $("#my-div ul li");
    if ($html.hasClass("current") || $html.hasClass("extra")) {
        $(".btn-1 a").click();}
    else if ($html.hasClass("current") || $html.hasClass("extra2")) {
        $(".btn-2 a").click();}
});
</script>
```

So one list item has class **current + extra**, and the other list item hasClass **current + extra2**.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Currently it does not work as should be.

It currently will always trigger ".btn-1" to click and does not look at the other statements. I think it just looks at the "current" class and not if also the "extra" or "extra2" class is in the same li item.

Comment: "*Currently it does not work as should be*": can you explain that a little more? What is it doing and what should it be doing?

Comment: For starters, you're attempting to click the `a` element within an `a` element for the first if statement. Also, because you're using or operators, `||`, the if statement is going to fire for both I believe.

Comment: And just to be clear, you want an anchor to be clicked as soon as the page loads based on what `<li>` has specific classes?

Comment: You need to learn how boolean logic works. This is an extremely simple problem of confusing `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var $html = $("#my-div ul li.current");
    if ($html.hasClass("extra")) {
        $(".btn-1 a a").click();}
    else if ($html.hasClass("extra2")) {
        $(".btn-2 a").click();}
});
</script>
```

The problem is, when you do `$html.hasClass("current") || ..` it would always evalutate to true and would not go to the `else` clause when node has a class `current`

Comment: Wouldn't `$html` then become a `boolean` result and not a DOM collection (since the final right-hand operation is `hasClass`)? Maybe perhaps make it `$html = $('#my-div ul li.current')`?

Answer (score 1):

You are making a comparison of `a or b` where you need `a and b` so change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var $html = $("#my-div ul li");
    if ($html.hasClass("current") && $html.hasClass("extra")) {
        $(".btn-1 a a").click();}
    else if ($html.hasClass("current") && $html.hasClass("extra2")) {
        $(".btn-2 a").click();}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$html.hasClass("current") || $html.hasClass("extra")
```

with

```
$html.hasClass("current") && $html.hasClass("extra")
```

and also

```
$html.hasClass("current") || $html.hasClass("extra2")
```

with

```
$html.hasClass("current") && $html.hasClass("extra2")
```

Answer (score 0):

The original root of the problem is that you're using or (`||`) and not and (`&&`) when testing for classes. You're asking "if li has class current OR extra".

However, you can also refactor it a bit and make it a little cleaner as well:

```
// first, grab the <li> marked as current
var $current = $('#my-div ul li.current');
// test if we have a match and proceed
if ($current.size()){
    // cache the final target selector (by initializing it to `false` we
    // can later test and only execute the click when we have a match)
    var target = false;

    // now get in to second-level classes (can use either `.is()` or
    // `.hasClass()` (thought I'd show an alternative method as well))
    if ($current.hasClass('.extra')) target = '.btn-1 a a';
    else if ($current.hasClass('.extra2')) target = '.btn-2 a';
    // else if ($current.hasClass('...')) target = '...'; // more tests

    // see if we found a match and click it
    if (target) $(target).click();
}
```

Comment: Use `hasClass('extra')` instead `.is('.extra')`, it's much less work to use `hasClass` than it is to parse an arbitrary selector with `is`. I would also suggest `null` as an initializer for your target; it has the semantics you're looking for (no object/value yet) versus `false` which has very different semantics.

Comment: Indeed, `.hasClass` is less overhead; I Just thought I'd show another way to skin the cat 'tis all. ;-) And RE:false init value, I was trying to keep it clear to OP without getting in to JS's falsy evaluation. But you're right, null is a better fit.